# Are there ways to have Mac OS recognize my password "better"?

Tags: macos, keyboard, password

Basically I am "at odds" with Mac OS on how to properly type my password.

Meaning: when I used Linux (ubuntu with unity to be precise), I really didn't care about the "state" of my Linux box. If the screen saver/lock was up, I just started typing my password and hit enter. And ... I was logged in. Because the Linux screen lock was smart enough to understand that the string I typed + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is my password.

With Mac OS, on the other hand, I have to be much more "careful". I often find myself first type a letter, and press enter, and then when the input text field starts reflecting me typing ... I slowly type my password, and carefully press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Because: if I don't do that, Mac OS will try to use maybe 5 out of 8 chars I typed. Or something else. So far too often, it takes me two, three turns before I successfully unlocked my screen.

Long story short: is that me not fitting Mac OS (so I have to change my attitude of just typing pretty fast) - or are there ways to adapt Mac OS to my style of entering the unlock password?

(And yes, when I have the lid open, I use the fingerprint reader, works fine - but within the office, the lid is down.)

Comment: I don't have a lid, so that may complicate the issue, but for me if the screen's asleep it's tap space bar, count to 3, type pw, enter. I'm in before the screen's finished waking.

Comment: It used to work if you shook the mouse first, but these days it's space bar to wake, even if it's just the screen asleep, not actually the computer itself. I'll drop it into an answer.

Comment: This is one of the most annoying things about OS X. Especially if your the type of person who (wisely) has a long-ish password. Thanks for asking this.

Comment: Windows 10 does this too. It's exceedingly annoying. It feels like it was designed by people that never type passwords.

Comment: @Clonkex The behaviour you and OP describe is only present on slow machines. On my modern desktop I can type my password as fast as I want and it'd log me in immediately

Comment: I have a similar issue logging into Ubuntu.

Comment: @ИвоНедев I am working with the latest 2017 Mac Book Pro "Touch". Rest assured: this **is** a problem even on latest greatest hardware.

Comment: @Clonkex It annoys me too, but I assumed it's a security feature - it requires you to wait on the lock screen to *actually appear*, so you don't type your password into a random application by accident. If you're also using "Ctrl+Alt+Del to login", there's no way for an application on your machine to pretend to be the lock screen. If it bothers you too much, you can disable the lock screen (this doesn't keep your computer unlocked, it just gets you straight to the password dialog).

Comment: I had kind of the opposite problem with Windows 10 until I got used to it - I would hit a key to wake up the screen and get the password prompt, only to realize (sometimes too late, especially if the key was "enter") that the password box got whatever I hit.  Now that I'm used to it I love it and find it annoying that the OS X password box apparently doesn't exist when the screen is off...

Comment: @ИвоНедев Not at all. Both my work and home computers are very high-end machines, both with SSDs, and on both I have to wait several seconds before the password box appears and is ready to accept a password.

Comment: @Luaan I generally consider myself pretty knowledgeable when it comes to Windows, but this is something I haven't heard of. How do you disable the lock screen?

Comment: @Clonkex I was pretty sure there was a setting in the UI for there, but it seems that you need to edit the group policies (Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization -> Do not display the lock screen), though that may only work on Enterprise/Server versions of Windows. Another option is modifying the registry (though that will probably be reset on every larger Windows update, *sigh*).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you press the modifier keys (Command, Option, Control, Shift), it will wake the computer but not type anything, so you can press them as many times as you like without messing up your password.

I usually just drum on the modifier keys until I see the password cursor, after having exactly the problem you describe.

Comment: I find that the password cursor appears, yet macOS is _still_ not ready to accept my password, so it ignores the first few keys.

Comment: Exactly. The most annoying thing here is that *inconsistency* part.

Comment: Incidentally, this is also the habit I have in the OPs original scenario, i.e., I (superfluosly, apparently) hit Ctrl a few times before I start entering my password ... Maybe I take the lesson from this question and stop doing that :)

Comment: In particular, if your password starts with a capital letter or special character, you can keep shift held down, then type the first character once the screen turns on. It feels like you are just typing your password normally.

Comment: I used to drum on the modifier keys, but everytime I did that on a Windows box, it took me into assistive mode, and then I had to do even more stuff to get out of it.  So this turned out to be just as bad a habit as waking the computer with the first letter of your password.

Comment: @Harper That's StickyKeys, which can be disabled if you don't want it to appear.

Answer (score 13):

Every time you try to enter your password incorrectly, it will reject it and **highlight** the incorrect try.

#### Solution

Mash the keyboard (type random charcters) until you see characters appear, hit `enter`<sup>1</sup> (accepting you will be incorrect), and then type the correct password (which will thus overwrite the highlighted incorrect password).

<sup>1</sup>If you prefer not to hit enter (because maybe you have 3rd party software which locks you out after x attempts):

- `cmd`+`delete` clears the whole line behind your cursor
- `option`+ `delete` clears the whole word behind your cursor

#### Why this is better than other suggested methods

I find this to be the fastest way to get around MacOS not recognizing when typing starts, because you get immediate feedback on when input begins to be recognized--something you won't get if you just tap one of the modifier keys. You also don't have to needlessly wait extra time if it begins to recognize input quickly--which is what you'd have to do if you always wait 5 seconds after you wake, and before you begin typing, for example.

Answer (score 2):

If the screen is asleep then just tap space bar (once only or the 2nd tap will be the first char of the password); then either wait until the screen wakes fully, or just count to 3, type your password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It used to work if you shook the mouse first, but these days it's space bar to wake, even if it's just the screen asleep, not actually the computer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bad habit.  Waking the screen from screen-saver with the first letter of your password is an inherently unreasonable thing to do, for several reasons.  The first is that the computer may not yet have switched to the *state* in which the password-acceptance application is in focus, and the password box has keyboard focus.

If the password-entry box is not in focus, then what happens to your keystrokes is disturbingly unpredictable.  Not least (on systems where security is an issue), it creates a huge security hole, where you have no typed your password into whatever application does have focus.

It was sloppy of Linux to allow this to work.  As others have suggested, wake it up with "shift".  Do not drum the shift key, or you'll be unhappy everytime you wake a Windows machine.

Comment: I don't buy that. I am not *waking* my computer. It has the screen lock up and running. I exactly know where my typing goes. ( and for the record: I am talking about my "business laptop" - which has a very well defined software stack ... this is not some windows box that sits somewhere where 5 people install all kinds of software they pick up from the internet )

Comment: "typed your password into whatever application does have focus" - any OS allowing to access any application before unlocking from screen lock is broken. "It was sloppy of Linux to allow this to work" - why it is sloppy to do this assuming that lock screen works correctly (is not allowing access to any programs)?

Comment: That explanation is just an excuse. You're saying the letters need to go to the lock screen while the computer is locked, which is something people agree with. You're also saying that's not possible, which is obviously incorrect: At best it's non-trivial to implement.

Comment: @Peter I don't think I'm saying that.  I'm saying if you don't have positive visual feedback as to what you're typing your password into, you should not be typing your password.

Comment: @GhostCat errata noted and my apologies.  I did not realise your system did not have any security risks.  You should really state that as part of your question, since that is an unusual situation.  I would leave this answer up, as it will help the majority of others who do have security risks.